# Rollup trigger: Working on insert and update but giving error on deleting records

Tags: apex, trigger, salesforcedx, after-trigger

Here is the scenario! I've student object(Parent object) with fields-:

**Name**

**T_Amount__c**

and course object(child) with fields-:

**Name,**

**FeeAmount__c,**

**Student__c(lookup field)**

I've written a trigger where on adding values on FeeAmount__c in child, the parent object field T_Amount__c should be updated with sum(FeeAmount__c).

**Problem:** My trigger is working for both insert and update but it is not letting me delete any records in course object.

Here is my code for the same please have a look.

```
Trigger SumTotalFees on Course__c  (after insert, after update, after delete) {
    
    Set<Id> studentIds = new Set<Id>();
    List<Student__c> StudentsToUpdate = new List<Student__c>();

    for (Course__c c : Trigger.new) {
        studentIds.add(c.Student__c);
    }

    if (Trigger.isUpdate || Trigger.isDelete) {
        for (Course__c c : Trigger.old) {
            StudentIds.add(c.Student__c);
        }
    }

    Map<id, Student__c> studentMap = new Map<id, Student__c>([select id, T_Amount__c  from Student__c where id IN :studentIds]);

    List<AggregateResult> ars = [SELECT Student__c, sum(FeeAmount__c) FROM Course__c WHERE Student__c  IN :studentIds group by Student__c ];
    
    for (AggregateResult ar : ars) {
        studentMap.get(String.valueOf(ar.get('Student__c'))).T_Amount__c  = Integer.valueOf(ar.get('expr0'));
        StudentsToUpdate.add(studentMap.get(String.valueOf(ar.get('Student__c'))));
    }
    update StudentsToUpdate;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After delete does not have `Trigger.new`, so you should add if-clause to the first for-loop like:

```
if (Trigger.isUpdate || Trigger.isInsert) {
    for (Course__c c : Trigger.new) {
        studentIds.add(c.Student__c);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Just learnt new thing from you :) I Appreciate your help